# Graceful shutdown of Java GRPC server with streams

Tags: grpc-java

I'm trying to add graceful shutdown for my GRPC service that has some streaming APIs. Basically I want to wait for all GRPC calls to complete before shutting down my application. Streaming calls can take up to several minutes(big file uploads) and it seems current GRPC Java implementation is not respecting such use case.

My service is implemented in Java and uses GRPC 1.7.0. So I simply call `grpcServer.shutdown()` which according to the docs should:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which preexisting calls continue but new calls are rejected.

After it I immediately call `grpcServer.awaitTermination()` to block until my services in `TERMINATED` state.

But I see that GRPC actually waits at most 5 seconds before sending service in a `TERMINATED` state even though there are active streams.

So is seems `grpcServer.shutdown()` is not doing what the docs says it does and I wonder what should I do to support my use case. I think GRPC should support it(seems like a pretty common use case). If not I will need to track active streams manually which is doable not looks more like a hack.

Answer (score 3):

It appeared to be not that easy so I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@fedor/shutting-down-grpc-services-gracefully-961a95b08f8).

**TLDR:** One need to implement counting of open streams.